# How to make the selectList to show the default value as the selected item in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project. I have a dropdownlist like the following that gets its data via ViewData in Controller.

```
  <div id="displaySelectList" style="display:none;">
                                @Html.DropDownList("reason", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["reason"], "Value", "Text"), "select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "reason" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessage("reason", "select", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
```

The first item is the default item of the DropDownList. Now the problem is after choosing an item from that and after again opening the DropDownList, the user can see the former selected item as the default while I want it to show the "select" item as the default.I appreciate if anyone could suggests me a solution.

Comment: The selected option won't change unless the page refresh, maybe you can show us the complete view codes.

Comment: I'm displaying it on a modal and after closing it and again selecting the related button, it displays the modal but the dropdownlist shows the former chosen data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to reset the dropdown

```
function resetSelectElement(){
    $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
}
```

Call this function when you close the modal.